# File returns garbage, but writes correctly

Tags: c, file, fopen, fwrite

I'm writing a struct into a file, but it returns garbage. Here is my code:

```
ptFile = fopen("funcionarios.dat", "ab+");
fwrite(&novoFunc, sizeof(strFunc), 1, ptFile);
```

The values of struct novoFunc, before and after the fwrite are not garbage.
However, when I return the file values:

```
ptFile = fopen("funcionarios.dat", "rb+");
[...]

fseek(ptFile, i*sizeof(strFunc), SEEK_SET); //on the loop, i goes from 0 to total structs
fread(&funcionario, sizeof(strFunc), 1, ptFile);

printf("Code: %d; Name: %s; Address: %s; CPF: %d; Sales: %d\n", funcionario.codigo, funcionario.nome, funcionario.endereco, funcionario.cpf, funcionario.numVendas);
```

Any idea why? The code was working fine, and I dont remember doing significative changes.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Struct definition

```
typedef struct func{

    int codigo;
    char nome[50];
    char endereco[100];
    int cpf;
    int numVendas;
    int ativo;


} strFunc;
```

Edit2: It just got weirder: it works fine on linux (using netbeans and gcc compiler), but it doesnt on windows (devcpp and codeblocks). Well, the entire code is here:

http://pastebin.com/XjDzAQCx

the function cadastraFucionario() register the user, and when I use listaFuncionarios(), to list all the registered data, it returns the garbage. Here is a print of what listaFuncionarios() returns:

http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/3002/asodfadhf.jpg

Im sorry the code isnt in english

Comment: You should check the return value of `fread()` to see that the read is even succeeding. A failed read would be an easy explanation for seeing garbage.

Comment: Are both `novoFunc` and `funcionario` of type `strFunc`?

Comment: @FatalError What should fread return? It returned sometimes 1, and others 0, but in both cases the result was garbage in a few "struct variables" and correct value on others.

edit: all the variables are garbage, not a few

Comment: @sarnold Yes, both novoFunc and funcionario belongs to strFunc

Comment: could you share the `struct strFunc` definition !

Comment: @JayD Sorry. Here it goes:

typedef struct func{

    
    int codigo;

    char nome[50];

    char endereco[100];

    int cpf;

    int numVendas;

    int ativo;



} strFunc;

Comment: Check `fwrite()`; it will return 1 if it successfully wrote one record and zero otherwise.  Check `fread()`; it will return 1 if it successfully read one record and zero otherwise.  If either fails, then you have no reliable data to work with.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler fwrite returns 1; the fread returns 1 always, except by the last time. (probably due to EOF).. But whenever my fread returns 1, the data should be valid, shouldn't it?

Comment: When `fread()` returns 1, it read as many bytes from the file as there are bytes in the structure.  If the data in the file was good, then the data read should be OK.  Otherwise, GIGO.  Your structure is serializable without further ado; it does not have any pointers in it, for example.  So, it should work.  But it is going to be hard to debug without the code.  Maybe you should remove the data file and start over.  Write one record; print it too.  Then do a hex dump of the file to see whether the data it contains matches what it should.

Comment: Another simple check, assuming a conventional system where `int` is a 4-byte quantity that is 4-byte aligned, then your structure will be 168 bytes long (166 data bytes, 2 bytes padding after the second string to get 4-byte alignment).  Write one record to a new file.  Check that the file is in fact 168 bytes long.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I used a hex editor right now and the .dat file is correct. Now, the first two structs are returning the correct value, the others returns garbage.
edit: It is 168 bytes long

Comment: If two reads are working, then you're well on the way.  Are you doing something else silly, like returning a pointer to a local structure in the function that reads the record?  The problem probably moves from being the read or write operations themselves to how you handle the data after you've read it.

Comment: do you explictly store '\0' in structure members nome and endereco? If not can you try and getback. Also provide a sample of the garbage o/p you see, so that we can be more precise.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with RoyalJai, you've covered enough simple cases at this point that I'd like to see the kind of garbage returned.

Comment: @RoyalJai No, but it  was working fine a few days ago :s And it just got weirder: it works fine on linux (using netbeans and gcc compiler), but it doesnt on windows (devcpp and codeblocks). Well, the entire code is here: http://pastebin.com/XjDzAQCx

the function cadastraFucionario() register the user, and when I use listaFuncionarios(), to list all the registered data, it returns the garbage. Here is a print of what listaFuncionarios() returns:

http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/3002/asodfadhf.jpg

Im sorry the code isnt in english

Comment: On the print, at field 'endereco' the names are ok, but it adds a few caracteres before. on 'nome' field, the first one is valid, but the second got empty. the others numbers are randomic, except by 'codigo' and 'ativo', where 256, 512 and 65536 are well-known numbers. But I have no idea why they are there. As you can see in the code, line 150, I define struct.ativo as equals to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> it works fine on linux ... but it doesnt on windows

is a big red flag. Windows has "text" files which are different to "binary" files. On Linux and other Unixes, there is no difference.

Two lines in your source stand out:

```
fopen("funcionarios.dat", "rb+");
```

and later

```
fopen("funcionarios.dat", "r+");
```

That is, sometimes you open the file in "binary" mode, and sometimes in "text" mode. Make sure you always open any file in "binary" mode (that is, with the `b` in the mode string) if you ever intend to read or write non-text data.

Comment: Yay! Its working now, thanks. The problem was both the error you two related (I didnt close the ptFile in a few moments and I didnt opened always with binary); Such a lame error that cost me a few days of headache. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

You say: "The code was working fine, and I dont remember doing significative changes."

When it was working fine, it wrote some structures into your file.

Maybe later it was still working fine, and it appended some additional structures at the end of your file.  The original data still remained at the beginning of your file.  So when you read the beginning of the file, you read the original data.  Maybe.

Are you sure that you read garbage?  Are you sure that you didn't just read old data?

In your code:

```
ptFile = fopen("funcionarios.dat", "ab+");
```

Appending is the right thing to do for some purposes but not for others.  Do you need wb+ instead?

Comment: I deleted the .dat files several times to ensure no errors were afflicting my readings. Also, I've checked the struct variables value before and after the fwrite function, and they are correct.

I didnt use wb+ because it would overwrite the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two problems in your function retornaIndice.

```
while(!feof(ptFile)){
    fseek(ptFile, sizeof(strFunc)*i, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&tmpFunc, sizeof(strFunc), 1, ptFile);
```

You aren't checking the result of fread.  After reading the last record, eof has not been reached yet, so you will try another read.  That read will reach eof and will return 0, but you aren't checking for that 0, so you will use garbage data and will exit the loop the next time the while statement tests it.

```
if(codigo != 0 && tmpFunc.ativo){                   
    if(tmpFunc.codigo == codigo){
        return i;                               
    }
```

If you detect a problem at this point, you don't close ptFile.  The leaked handle shouldn't cause garbage data to be written to the file, but it doesn't inspire confidence either.

Some of your other functions have the same errors.

Comment: Yay! Its working now, thanks. The problem was both the error you two related (I didnt close the ptFile in a few moments and I didnt opened always with binary); Such a lame error that cost me a few days of headache. Thanks all!